# Wildcards in Sails: Is it possible to have wild cards in a contains URL?

Tags: angular, express, orm, sails.js, waterline

Here is my URL. I am trying to have the contains have a wild card so i can attach 2 values together.

`http://localhost:1337/ProductDepartments?where={"or":[{"ProductDepartmentId":{"contains":"1+*"}}]}`

This is reference to the 2 input boxes that ng2-table has. My example is different since my data is loaded dynamically compared to all the data loaded at once. I just can't do that. Too many rows.

The 2 input boxes impact each other. 
In this example, the first input box has A and then second input box has C. The first input box filters out all the rows that do not contain a capital A in them. The second input box then filters out all names that do not contain a capital C.
Image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7uCk.png)

What wildcard can i use? Is it possible to maybe run both and then do a matching? Compare Arrays to see if like elements exist?

Comment: Are you trying to send a json body via GET or I get it wrong ?

Comment: I'm trying to filter on a column twice on a GET.

Comment: I'm attempting that second method where I do 2 GETs and then intersect the arrays.